# How to add touch dispatcher in Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:
    self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

this is the old method in version 2.0.
but it says (in 3.0): `no visible interface for CCDirector for selector touchDispatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no touchDispatcher in 3.0

The new method for detecting touches is:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
```

Be sure you added

```
[self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

If you want to detect a touch in a zone just do this:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:NODE];
```

And if you want to track every touch or count how many touches you have, you will need to make an array, and when a touch began, add it to the array, and when it ends, remove it.

Hope this helps.